# Did opencv use some acceleration technology(i.e. opencl) on gaussian blur?

Tags: opencv, opencl, neon

I implement my own gaussian filter by C++ and neon.

Pseudo code：

```
oneDimensionBlur(src, temp1, width, height)    //implement by C++
transposeMatrix(temp1, temp2, width, height)   //implement by neon
oneDimensionBlur(temp2, temp1, height, width)
transposeMatrix(temp1, dst, height, width)
```

But the cv::GaussianBlur() is almost 8 times faster than my implementation! I almost desperate for the profiling result. So I want to ask if opencv use any acceleration technology on gaussian blur? I try to track the opencv source code but failed.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV can definetly use parallelism techniques for accelerating `cv::GaussianBlur`. Look [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/smooth.dispatch.cpp#L480-L550) for its implementation. As you can see, there are in that file at least 3 parallelized versions of the function, using OpenCL, IPP or OpenVX.

There is some functionality to disable optimizations, such as [`setUseOptimized`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#ga3c8487ea4449e550bc39575ede094c7a) or [`setUseOpenCL`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dc/d83/group__core__opencl.html#gadb3b41d4552e9db7887855e3a1b2af37). See functions at the bottom of [this](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html?highlight=setnumthreads#void%20setNumThreads%28int%20nthreads%29) page for more ways to control the multithreading.

In the end, it might be the easier to build OpenCV from source, disable all things like OpenCL, and run it on a single thread (use `setNumThreads`).

Comment: Thanks. But how to disable all acceleration technologies when compiling source code?

Comment: I think using `cmake -D WITH_TBB=OFF -D WITH_OPENMP=OFF -D WITH_IPP=OFF ..` should disable them all. Also try using the `setNumThreads`. Check with `ps` the number of threads your application is using to make sure it works.